# VB.NET - Accessing My.MySettings.Default changes Thread.CurrentPrincipal?

Tags: vb.net, authentication, identity, principal

It appears that when you access My.Settings.Default in VB.NET, your thread's CurrentPrincipal changes. Consider the following code.

```
            Dim name = "admin"
            Dim user = Membership.GetUser(name)
            Dim identity = New GenericIdentity(user.UserName)
            Dim principal = New RolePrincipal(identity)

            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal
            Debug.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name)
            Dim x = My.MySettings.Default
            Debug.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name)
```

The output of this code is

> admin
>
> MyDomain\MyUserName

Is this expected? Is it documented anywhere? I couldn't find any references to it.

It also seems to only do this the first time My.MySettings.Default is accessed, which means that a workaround might be to touch the property to initialize it before attempting to set the thread's CurrentPrincipal. Would there be any undesirable side effects to doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is because the default instance is created using a thread-safe operation:

```
    Private Shared defaultInstance As MySettings = CType(Global.System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(New MySettings), MySettings)
```

Since the default instance is only created the first time you access MySettings, I think the easiest solution is to access it once prior to changing your user identity.